# Emoji-picker incompatible with IvoryCKEditorBundle in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, emoji, sonata

I want to add Emoji to one of my forms using [Emoji-picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker) in my cms that is built with Symfony and Sonata. But I realize that is not working when you have also added the IvoryCKEditorBundle.

I have this button on the backend:

```
 <p >
   <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Input field" data-emojiable="true">
</p>
```

And when I executed:

```
window.emojiPicker.discover();
```

The plugin create the component:

```
<div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor form-control cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" data-id="06986ad8-e870-4cc2-a00d-16ca23b47e71" data-type="input" placeholder="Input field" contenteditable="true" style="height: 33px; position: relative;" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor2" title="Rich Text Editor, editor2" aria-describedby="cke_180"></div>
```

The problem is that is also adding the class for the CkeditorBundle and the Emojis are not added to the input.

Instead of that the input is:

[image]

Important to know is that the same example out of the sonata admin bundle is working well.

Someone know what is happening, or how can I work around this problem?

Comment: Have you check this issue ? https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker/issues/32 , or do you want to use ckeditor with emoji-picker ?

Comment: I didn't check this issue and it seems that is exactly what is happening to me. I just try but and right now I don't have the ckeditor but it is still not working. I keep trying   and if I find something I will write the answer here,